# Changing the Active Directory on an existing install of Windows HPC Pack 2019

Tags: windows, server, cluster-computing, hpc

I have an existing Windows HPC Pack 2019 install that is currently only working with an Administrator login.

I want to change it to work with a newly set up Active Directory. Is there a way to do this, or does it necessitate a reinstall? I can't find any documentation on it.

I looked at the menus and read up on the PowerShell commands. Nothing seemed to suggest it is possible without reinstallation.

Comment: Is this a Server Core installation, or does it have the full Desktop Experience available?

Comment: Full Dektop Experience